# Android Error while using Retrofit2 and XML

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to make a simple Get Request with Retrofit and Simple XML but i get the following error. I cant understand what im doing wrong since color is an element and its not missing from any category.

The error:

```
I/System.out: FAILED : org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=color, required=true, type=class java.lang.String) on field 'color' public java.lang.String me.limetag.zwz.models.Category.color for class me.limetag.zwz.models.Category at line 4
```

My models:

```
@Root
public class Categories implements Serializable
{    
@ElementList
private List<Category> category;

public List<Category> getCategory ()
{
    return category;
}

public void setCategory (List<Category> category)
{
    this.category = category;
}

}


@Root
public class Category implements Serializable
{
 @Element(name="id",type=Integer.class)
 public Integer id;

 @Element(name="color",type=String.class)
 public String color;

 @Element(name="name",type=String.class)
 public String name;
}
```

The Call:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIURL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .build();

    ZService service = retrofit.create(ZService.class);
    service.getCategories().enqueue(new Callback<Categories>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Categories> call, Response<Categories> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Categories categoryList = response.body();
                List<Category> categories = categoryList.getCategory();
                for (Category category: categories
                     ) {
                        String name = category.getName();
                        Log.e("DONE",name);
                }
            }
        }
```

The XML:

```
<categories>
<category>
    <id>8</id>
    <name>BEVERAGES</name>
    <color>#00B392</color>
</category>
<category>
    <id>8</id>
    <name>BEVERAGES</name>
    <color>#00B392</color>
</category>
</categories>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried reversing the process and print out the JAVA classes using simple XML and this is what i got. I dont understand from where its getting the extra category node.

```
<categories>
<category class="java.util.ArrayList">
 <category>
  <color>#000000</color>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>NAME</name>
 </category>
 <category>
  <color>#000000</color>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>NAME</name>
 </category>
 <category>
  <color>#000000</color>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>NAME</name>
 </category>
</category>
```

Comment: Well you've got the Outer class `Categories` and then you have the element `category` in it that is a list of `Category` elements.

Comment: it wouldnt work with me on this one so i just changed the server return into json and used GsonConverter. Thank you for your reply !

Comment: Np! I was searching for a similar solution and ended up finding http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#scatter which points out `@ElementList` with the `inline=true` and this was what finally got me getting errors so that I could fix the rest^^ (was just getting null objects) Glad you found a solution either way^^